# python: record score/user and display top 10

Tags: python, python-3.6

I'm making a trivia exercise in python 3.6.3 as part of an exercise at work. I have the whole script running successfully and triggering responses at the end correctly while tallying up the score correctly.It starts off like this:

```
#!python3.6
## greet user, take name, explain rules ##
print ('HELLO! WELCOME TO MY MOVIE TRIVIA QUIZ. \n')
name = input('WHAT IS YOUR NAME?')
print ('\n WELCOME TO THE THUNDERDOME ' + name + '! SHALL WE PLAY A GAME? \n')
print ('I WILL ASK YOU 10 MOVIE TRIVIA QUESTIONS AND YOU SHALL HAVE 3 CHOICES FOR ANSWERS.\n \n PLEASE ANSWER IN A ABC FORMAT.\n \n CHOOSE WISELY, FOR YOU SHALL BE JUDGED\n')
print ('IMPORTANT DISCLAIMER FOR MORTALS : PLEASE KEEP YOUR CAPS LOCK ON')
print ('\n-----------------------------------------------------------\n')
##set the score at 0##
score = 0
score = int(score)
```

This repeats for 10 questions ending with: `#### Final score with if/elif parameters. percentage threshold is set up so I can add more questions down the line and  I'm researching how to set some sort of recorded score function or top score board with user.

```
####
print ('Prepare to be judged: ' + str(score) + ' out of 10') 
percentage = (score/10)*100
print ('The verdict is:', percentage)
if percentage < 20.0:
    print ('I Dont normally judge people, but you need to see more movies and have no culture.')
elif percentage >=20.1 and percentage <=40.0:
    print ('Nice, there is some hope for you.')
elif percentage >=40.1 and percentage <=60.0:
    print ('Ohhhh, you fancy yourself a trivia buff? step correct next time.')
elif percentage >=60.1 and percentage <=80.0:
    print ('Color me impressed! You are getting closer.')
elif percentage >=80.1 and percentage <=99.9:
    print ('You are gonna break the game, you are on fire!.')
if percentage ==100.0:
    print ('I HAVE VIEWED UPON YOUR MIND AND DEEMED THAT YOU ARE WORTHY OF GODHOOD')
print ('\n-----------------------------------------------------------\n')
```

What I would like to do, is record score/user and display the top 10 at the end and have it be persistent. I'm having a hard time finding a good source example of something like that so I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Your question has 2 parts. 1, how to print top 10 user. 2, how to store it to a file. Do some research on how to read/write csv files with python. Then you will be able to store the scores into a file. The first question is simple, just need to iterate through all the users, then find the max.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest after the user finishes the quiz, to append their result to a file like so:

```
# Writing high scores to file
file = open('highscores.txt','a')
name='foo';score=78
file.write(name + " " + str(score) + "\n")
name='bobby';score=56
file.write(name + " " + str(score) + "\n")
file.close()
```

Then read that file, sort by the scores, and print the result:

```
# Reading/Printing the output
file = open('highscores.txt').readlines()
scores_tuples = []
for line in file:
    name, score = line.split()[0], float(line.split()[1])
    scores_tuples.append((name,score))
scores_tuples.sort(key=lambda t: t[1], reverse=True)
print("HIGHSCORES\n")
for i, (name, score) in enumerate(scores_tuples[:10]):
    print("{}. Score:{} - Player:{}".format(i+1, score, name))
HIGHSCORES

1. Score:99.0 - Player:joe
2. Score:78.0 - Player:foo
3. Score:56.0 - Player:bobby
```

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly what I'm looking for.